# MVC status page response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

If some specific request coming to MVC web site, e.g status.aspx how i may dynamically create a response e.g "Server1 OK" without creating any additional controllers to process this request.

We have web farm and each of the sites should response " OK" when status.aspx requested.

Or i should create for example controller Status and redirect to this controller if status.aspx requested. In such case question is how i may redirect from to Status when status.aspx requested.

Answer (score 1):

In your ActionResult you can inject the response header. This can be done on any existing controller.

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Net

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class MyFunkyController: Inherits MyApp.Core.Base.BaseController

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Return View()
        End Function

        Function Foo() As ActionResult
            Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Return View()
        End Function

        Function Bar() As ActionResult
            Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Alternatively you can set this in your BaseController (but I wouldn't recommend it)

```
    Protected Overrides Function CreateActionInvoker() As System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker
            Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    End Function
```

Comment: PS: sorry for the VB, but the principles are the same. Just use http://converter.telerik.com to get the CSharp version.

Comment: How i may check that request for status.aspx comes and request it to controller?

Comment: Can you better explain the problem that you're having? I don't fully understand why you need to send the Status Code down the line.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at a feature called Routing. It allows you to map request URLs to controllers that are meant to process the response.